# Android AVD not loading in android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

After Installing the `intel HAXM`, when I launch the `AVD (emulator)`, it keeps me waiting forever showing the boot animation.

The `AVD (emulator)` just doesn't start.

I have tried it multiple times, but there seems to be some sort of issue that I am not able to understand. What is the problem or what am I missing?

I cannot test my applications if the emulator doesn't load completely.

It opens up but gets stuck at the boot animation.

Comment: What is your computer's specification?

Comment: 4 GB RAM, INTEL 3RD GEN i5. 2GB GFORCE NVIDEA CARD.

Answer (score 0):

YOu might get help and it might get solved but it is a known fact that the android emulator is slow. So, you might want to have a look at this : [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)